# ExtJS store create record with PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, extjs, crud

i want to add record in grid extjs with Ajaxproxy. here some code i got problem in backend php. i dont know how's data from model extjs send to url in store. i have success reader data from php backend couse store no need to send data.
please help.

**add record**

```
onAddClick: function(){
    var rec = new Writer.Person({
        real_name: '',
        username: '',
        email: ''
    }), edit = this.editing;

    edit.cancelEdit();
    this.store.insert(0, rec);
    edit.startEditByPosition({
        row: 0,
        column: 1
    });
}
```

**model**

```
Ext.define('Writer.Person', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
fields: [{
    name: 'id',
    type: 'int',
    useNull: true
}, 'email', 'real_name', 'username'],
validators: {
    email: {
        type: 'length',
        min: 1
    },
    real_name: {
        type: 'length',
        min: 1
    },
    username: {
        type: 'length',
        min: 1
    }
}
```

});

**store**

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'Writer.Person',
    autoLoad: true,
    autoSync: true,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        api: {
            read: 'index.php/master/getUser/',
            create: 'index.php/master/addUser/',
            update: 'index.php/master/updateUser/',
            destroy: 'index.php/master/deleteUser/'
        },
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            successProperty: 'success',
            root: 'data',
            messageProperty: 'message'
        },
        writer: {
            type: 'json',
            writeAllFields: false,
            root: 'data'
        },
        listeners: {
            exception: function(proxy, response, operation){
                Ext.MessageBox.show({
                    title: 'REMOTE EXCEPTION',
                    msg: operation.getError(),
                    icon: Ext.MessageBox.ERROR,
                    buttons: Ext.Msg.OK
                });
            }
        }
    },
    listeners: {
        write: function(proxy, operation){
            if (operation.action == 'destroy') {
                main.child('#form').setActiveRecord(null);
            }
            Ext.example.msg(operation.action, operation.getResultSet().message);
        }
    }
});
```

**php**

```
public function getUser(){
    $arr=array();
    $rs = $this->db->query("select email, id, username, real_name from t_users order by id")->result_array();
    if (is_array($rs)) {
        foreach($rs as $row)
        {
            $arr[] = $row;
        }
    }
    echo json_encode($arr);
}

public function addUser(){
    $data = array(
        'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
        'real_name' => $this->input->post('real_name'),
        'username' => $this->input->post('username')
    );
    $add = json_decode($this->db->insert('t_users',$data));
    echo json_encode($add);
    var_dump($this->session->all_userdata());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this. and is work

**php**

```
public function addUser(){
    $input_data = json_decode(trim(file_get_contents('php://input')), true);
    $data = $input_data['data'];
    $add = json_decode($this->db->insert('t_users',$data));
    echo json_encode($add);
}
```